# Error trying to install a library in Python

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pygame, pyinstaller

I'm trying to install the pygame library of python, to do it I use `pip install pygame` in the CMD of Windows, but then I get this error.

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\marcg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\marcg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c1fzrnpr\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\marcg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c1fzrnpr\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\marcg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-07h2j4on'
         cwd: C:\Users\marcg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c1fzrnpr\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\marcg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c1fzrnpr\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\marcg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c1fzrnpr\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\marcg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c1fzrnpr\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\marcg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c1fzrnpr\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install wheel before `pip install wheel` before installing pygame so it use already compiled package instead of trying to build it.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: Windows users please use `python` instead of `python3` and `pip` instead of `pip3`**

Try  `pip3 uninstall pygame`

and then  `python3 -m pip install -U pygame==2.0.0 --user`

To see if it works, run one of the included examples:
`python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens`

**If you get 'PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied', before starting the command prompt right click and "Run as administrator".**

If `pip3` is not there, **use `pip`**

**Make sure pip is updated.**
Watch this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABe_qpzQu0Q to learn about updating pip

Make sure to [Read pygame official docs about windows installation](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Windows%20installation)

Comment: I get the same error with pip3 install pygame==1.9.6

Comment: use 2.0.0 version

Comment: python3 is not recognised as a command (I'm using windows, maybe is for that)

Comment: Windows users please use python only instead of python3

Comment: I get the same error that is in the post :(

Comment: I tried both in my Linux and windows , and it worked without any problem. Make sure to check your system settings.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 doesn't support latest 1.9.6 pygame...
Try :

```
python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: If python3 is not recognized then, try : 
python -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6

Comment: I get another time the error that I post at the top of the post :(

Comment: Try running terminal as admin... and do this..

Comment: Upgrade your pip to the latest version ... and after that try doing python3.7.x -m pip install pygame  OR  python3.7.x -m pip install pygame===2.0.0.dev6  

Try these as admin and if these don't work try doing the same command without .x

Comment: I'm using python 3.9, maybe is for this that it doesn't work

Comment: @Gonsa02 yes. that is correct.